# Accessing Window Object from .tsx file

Tags: javascript, typescript, window-object

Typically in my `.ts` files I can access the window object by calling something such as:

```
(<any>window).myObject
```

I am getting compilation errors for this in my `.tsx` files. Is there any way I can access it from a `.tsx` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `as` syntax for type assertion. This is the alternate syntax for type assertion as `<type>obj` conflicts with JSX syntax:

```
(window as any).myObject
```

---

The above will work, however if you want strong typing consider [augmenting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) the `Window` interface to add your property so you will get compile-time type checking:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        myObject: YourObjectType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax `<type>` is being deprecated by the ts team. This is because there is too much ambiguity between it and the new `jsx` syntax. Instead the ts team introduced the `as` operator for type assertions.

So this syntax:

```
(window as any).things
```

is more update to date.

This change was done, because basically, its very tough to tell a compiler when is such a syntax relating to a type or a jsx-element. Likewise the notation becomes much harder to read (see below for example):

```
<Component>
  {<String>something}
</Component>
```

Some more detail can be found here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html#as-foo-vs-foo and here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/296

Answer (score 1):

Further Explanation on @Saravana Answer,

best way is to have this defined in your `types` folder, and add a definition file with `.d.ts` extention, i.e: `window.d.ts` and place your extended definitions for the window object, as typescript global augmentation typically offers merging interfaces.

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        myObject: YourObjectType;
    }
}

// but make sure to export that as default so Typescript will consider it automatically on the project
export default global;
```